# How to build multi v1/v5 records in one NetFlow packet#

Tags: scapy, netflow

From current scapy document and code，it seams there is no appropriate API to do this.

Ihope to add the API to build multi v1/v5 records in one NetFlow packet.

We need to build multi NetFlow records in one packet to simulate and test the packets just like the living network.